# Laravel One To One relation return BelongsTo and not the child

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 2 tables :

**Users**

```
id, name, email, password, parrainage_id, parrain_id
```

**Parrainages**

```
id, parrain_id, filleul_id, referral_token
```

It's a affiliation system, so parrain_id and filleul_id are equivalent of user_id.

** User class **

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

public function parrainage()
{
return $this->belongsTo('\App\Parrainage');
}

public function parrain()
{
return $this->hasOne('\App\User');
}
```

** Parrainage class **

```
class Parrainage extends Model
{

public function parrain()
{
return $this->hasOne('\App\User');
}

public function filleul()
{
return $this->hasOne('\App\User');
}
```

In a template i try to do

```
{{dd(Auth::user()->parrainage())}}
```

My user has a parrainage_id value setted. I would like to get the object Parrainage, but i get an object Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo instead.

Did i did something wrong in my relations ?

Thanks

Comment: remove the `()` after `parrainage()`, leave just `Auth::user()->parrainage` to get a model instance instead belongsTo instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @porloscerros. Actually it was pretty easy. I focused on the relation problem, and it was just the way to call it. haha. I love code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the relationship function (`->parrainage()`) will return the relationship query. You either need to execute the query manually, or call the relationship attribute (`->parrainage`) to have the query executed automatically.

```
 {{ dd(Auth::user()->parrainage()->first()) }}
```

or

```
 {{ dd(Auth::user()->parrainage) }}
```

---

Also, while not related to your question, your relationships on your `Parrainage` are not correct. Because the parrainages table contains the foreign keys (`parrain_id` and `filleul_id`), the `Parrainage` class is on the `belongsTo` side of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @patricus. Actually it was pretty easy. I focused on the relation problem, and it was just the way to call it.  haha. I love code